# Create semi-transparent Image Overlay

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I'm creating a one-page WordPress-theme. In each section there is a header with an image and an overlay.

The header has a background, within there is an image of a wrap-width. on bottom of that, there is a `png-image` which is semi-transparent and should be full-width, overlaying the header-image.

Since I'm using different styling for the sections, I'm numbering them and the overlay-image is in a different color for each section. So I should insert it through CSS.

Until now I just could make the overlay visible when I type in a height value. But since the page needs to be responsive, I want the height to be variable, and always 100% width.

[image]

**My Code:**

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&order=ASC'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<div id="content" class=" section-<?php echo $i++; ?>">
<h2 class="headline"><?php the_field('headline') ?></h2>
<div class="header">
    <div class="wrap cf">
        <?php
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
           the_post_thumbnail('bones-thumb-600');
           }
        else {

       }
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>    

<div id="inner-content" class="wrap cf">
    <div id="main" class="m-all">        
        <div class="stripes"></div>
            <!-- Thumbnail -->
            <a class="logo" href="#top"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo.png" /></a>                    

            <div class="sidebar">
               <?php the_field('sidebar') ?>
            </div>

            <div class="main-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

            <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/separator.svg"/>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`opacity: 0.5;` should be what you search, 0.0 is transparent and 1.0 is visible, so 0.5 would be 50% visible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is not the opacity. I'm looking for a way to display my image.

I have added this css-code, but my image won't appear. Just if I enter a height value. But I want the image to be responsive and alway 100% width of the browser.

background-image: url(../images/separator-orange.png);
background-size: 100% auto;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;
position: relative;

Comment: Ah then I misunderstood your question sorry, the title misled me x) For a responsive design you just need a variable width, if you want the height to change with the window width you can easily work with **media querys**. Also if there is content in the element is ist visible as well? Like a text or maybe `content: " "` might work too.

Answer (score 0):

Please do like this

```css
.image-holder{
  height: 200px;
  width:200px;
  position: relative;
  }
.image-holder:after{
    content:'';
  position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 top: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  }
```

```html
<div class="image-holder"><img src="images/img02.jpg" height="371" width="556" alt="image description"></div>
```